# Showing all values when at least match a given one

Tags: mysql

Given three tables **items**, **genres** and **itemGenres**; how can I filter out the items that have at least the given value while also outputting the rest of its genres.

With this data

```
INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES ('Mad Max: Fury Road'), ('The Big Lebowski');
INSERT INTO genres (genre) VALUES ('action'), ('comedy'), ('post-apocalyptic');
INSERT INTO itemGenres (itemId, genreId) VALUES (1,1), (1,3), (2,2);
```

and this query

```
SELECT 
  items.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(genres.id) as genreIds,
  GROUP_CONCAT(genres.genre) as genres FROM items
LEFT JOIN itemGenres ON
  items.id = itemGenres.itemId
LEFT JOIN genres ON
  genres.id = itemGenres.genreId
WHERE
  genres.id IN (1)
GROUP BY
  items.id
```

I get the following result

```
| id |              title | genreIds | genres |
|----|--------------------|----------|--------|
|  1 | Mad Max: Fury Road |        1 | action |
```

How do I get it to be this?

```
| id |              title | genreIds |                   genres |
|----|--------------------|----------|------------------------- |
|  1 | Mad Max: Fury Road |      1,3 | action, post-apocalyptic |
```

---

The tables are created like this

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `itemGenres` (
  `id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itemId` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `genreId` int(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `id` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `genre` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: Do you mean you want genreIDs 1,3? (you have 1,2 right now)

Comment: Yeah, just updated

Comment: See the LISTAGG function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 joins to `itemGenres`, separating the "check" logic (`WHERE genres.id IN (1)`) and the "gathering of all related genres":

```
SELECT 
  items.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(genres.id ORDER BY genres.id)    AS genreIds,
  GROUP_CONCAT(genres.genre ORDER BY genres.id) AS genres 
FROM items
  LEFT JOIN itemGenres ON
    items.id = itemGenres.itemId
  LEFT JOIN genres ON
    genres.id = itemGenres.genreId
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT *
    FROM itemGenres AS genre_check 
    WHERE genre_check.itemId = items.id
      AND genre_check.genreId IN (1)
  )
GROUP BY
  items.id ;
```

The `LEFT` joins can be replaced with `INNER` joins, the results would be identical.

---

Actually, it could be done with a change of your query, moving the check from `WHERE` to `HAVING` but the condition has to be modified:

```
SELECT 
  items.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(genres.id ORDER BY genres.id)    AS genreIds,
  GROUP_CONCAT(genres.genre ORDER BY genres.id) AS genres 
FROM items
  JOIN itemGenres ON
    items.id = itemGenres.itemId
  JOIN genres ON
    genres.id = itemGenres.genreId
GROUP BY
  items.id 
HAVING
  COUNT(CASE WHEN itemGenres.genreId IN (1) THEN 1 END) > 0 ;
```

My personal preference would be the 1st solution but you can test in your database, which of the two is more efficient.

Comment: Could I somehow expand one of the above solutions to require all of the values in the `IN` clause? Example: `IN (1,2)` would return items that have genres 1, 2 and 3 but not items that only have genre 1

Comment: I'd think that `IN (1,2)` would return items with either 1 or 2 or both. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, that is what's happening. What I meant is that I want it to require both. But it could also be more than that. So one item with three genres (`#1,#2,#3`) which matches both #1 and #2 would be included but not one item with one genre (`#1`) which matches genre #1 but not genre #2.

Comment: Ah, you want the other way, ok. That is a "relational division" problem. It can be solved with many ways, some similar to these queries.

Comment: In you second solution, switching the last row to `COUNT(CASE WHEN itemGenres.genreId IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) >= 2` maybe works. The last digit is simply the number of values in the `IN` clause. I've only done some quick testing and it seems to work.

Comment: Right, if the `(genreId, itemId)` combination is `UNIQUE`, then your query is correct.